# Forward slash not found in last string in line

Tags: python

My code is not very good but this is a really interesting problem. When looking for a forward slash in a string all are found except for if the forward slash is in the last word in the file. Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
if len(sys.argv)!=2:
    print "usage: %s filename\n" % (sys.argv[0]);
    exit(0);
f = open(sys.argv[1]);
lines = [i for i in f.readlines()]
finals = [];
for line in lines:
    words = line.split(",");
    for word in words:
            if word.find("/") != -1:
                    datefixes = word.split("/")
                    if datefixes[2].__len__() == 4:
                            temp = datefixes[2]
                            word = datefixes[0] + "-" + datefixes[1] + "-" + temp[-2:]
            finals += "," + word;
tempstring = ''.join(finals)
finallist = tempstring.split("\r\n")
finalstring = ""
for tmpstrpart in finallist:
    if tmpstrpart != "" or tmpstrpart !="\r\n":
            finalstring += tmpstrpart[1:] + "\r\n"
print finalstring
```

and here is a sample input

```
ACPVBF,1930-729,Z729,12/16/2014,6/10/2008,1/5/2003,44-48-46,39-43-41,35-39-37,29-33-31
ACPVGT,1930-729,Z729,25-29-27,19-23-21,14-18-16,7/11/2009,2/6/2004,48-2-0,42-46-44
ACPUQH,1930-729,Z729,32-40-19,26-34-13,21-29-8,14-22-1,9/17/1946,5/13/1942,49-7-36
ACPVOU,1930-729,Z729,42-0-29,36-44-23,31-39-18,24-32-11,19-27-6,15-23-2,9/17/1946
```

in the code these lines are split by commas. if the word at the end contains a / the forward slash is not found. but only if it is at the end. the rest work fine.

edit: The output I am currently getting on these lines is:

```
ACPVBF,1930-729,Z729,12-16-14,6-10-08,1-5-03,44-48-46,39-43-41,35-39-37,29-33-31
ACPVGT,1930-729,Z729,25-29-27,19-23-21,14-18-16,7-11-09,2-6-04,48-2-0,42-46-44
ACPUQH,1930-729,Z729,32-40-19,26-34-13,21-29-8,14-22-1,9-17-46,5-13-42,49-7-36
ACPVOU,1930-729,Z729,42-0-29,36-44-23,31-39-18,24-32-11,19-27-6,15-23-2,9/17/1946
```

the output that I am trying to get from these lines is:

```
ACPVBF,1930-729,Z729,12-16-14,6-10-08,1-5-03,44-48-46,39-43-41,35-39-37,29-33-31
ACPVGT,1930-729,Z729,25-29-27,19-23-21,14-18-16,7-11-09,2-6-04,48-2-0,42-46-44
ACPUQH,1930-729,Z729,32-40-19,26-34-13,21-29-8,14-22-1,9-17-46,5-13-42,49-7-36
ACPVOU,1930-729,Z729,42-0-29,36-44-23,31-39-18,24-32-11,19-27-6,15-23-2,[9-17-46]
```

I want the one with the brackets around it to change also.

final working code based on BrenBarn's answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import re
if len(sys.argv)!=2:
    print "usage: %s filename\n" % (sys.argv[0]);
    exit(0);
f = open(sys.argv[1]);
x = f.read()
f.close()
filename = sys.argv[1]
filename = filename[:-4] + " finished.csv"
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write(re.sub(r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/\d{2}(\d{2})', r'\1-\2-\3', x))
f.close()
```

Thanks for all the help. Sorry I can't upvote yet.

Comment: What is the output you get, and what is it you want instead?  When I try your code with that input, it seems to convert the final "9/17/1946" into "9-17-46", which as far as I can tell is what you want.

Comment: That is what I am wanting and its working except for the ones on the end of the lines for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my question with the output I am getting. Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: @SeanRodman Not an answer, but python has a built-in [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) package for loading comma separated values that you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I just got the program working finally. I should have probably researched a good bit more before I wrote the first rendition of the code, but here we are. I will look into the csv module for later programs. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I think what you're trying to do can be accomplished way more easily by just using a regular expression.

```
>>> print x
ACPVBF,1930-729,Z729,12/16/2014,6/10/2008,1/5/2003,44-48-46,39-43-41,35-39-37,29-33-31
ACPVGT,1930-729,Z729,25-29-27,19-23-21,14-18-16,7/11/2009,2/6/2004,48-2-0,42-46-44
ACPUQH,1930-729,Z729,32-40-19,26-34-13,21-29-8,14-22-1,9/17/1946,5/13/1942,49-7-36
ACPVOU,1930-729,Z729,42-0-29,36-44-23,31-39-18,24-32-11,19-27-6,15-23-2,9/17/1946
>>> print re.sub(r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/\d{2}(\d{2})', r'\1-\2-\3', x)
ACPVBF,1930-729,Z729,12-16-14,6-10-08,1-5-03,44-48-46,39-43-41,35-39-37,29-33-31
ACPVGT,1930-729,Z729,25-29-27,19-23-21,14-18-16,7-11-09,2-6-04,48-2-0,42-46-44
ACPUQH,1930-729,Z729,32-40-19,26-34-13,21-29-8,14-22-1,9-17-46,5-13-42,49-7-36
ACPVOU,1930-729,Z729,42-0-29,36-44-23,31-39-18,24-32-11,19-27-6,15-23-2,9-17-46
```

Comment: Is x a string or a list? Edit: nevermind. It's a string Thanks a lot man. You are a genius.

Comment: In this case it is a string, you could get it by just doing `x = f.read()` on your file.

Comment: Is there anyway to mark your comment as the answer or something like that? I already marked your post as useful.

Comment: I guess it didn't work because my rep is to low. Sorry. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your code is the trailing new line. My guess is it would fail for last word in each line. I would suggest you do a line.strip() before splitting